# Unequal rows in list from unstack() - how to create a dataframe

Tags: r

I am (trying) to do a Robust ANOVA analysis in R. This requires that my two variables are in a very specific format. Basically, the requirement is to unstack two columns in my current dataframe and form an outcome frequency dataframe based on the predictor (categorical variable). This would usually happen automatically using the unstack() function i.e. 
    `newDataFrame <- unstack(oldDataFrame, scores ~ columns)`
However, the list returned has unequal rows for each category. Here is an example:

```
$A
  [1] 2 4 2 3 3 
$B
 [1] 3 3 
$C
 [1] 5 
$D
[1] 4 4 3
```

A, B, C and D are my categories, and the numbers are the outcome. The outcome has to be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6.

What I am working towards is the category as the 'header' and the outcome as a reference column, with the frequencies as the other columns, such that the dataframe looks like this:

```
  A    B    C    D
1  NA   NA   NA   NA
2  2    NA   NA   NA
3  2    2    NA   1
4  1    NA   NA   2
5  NA   NA   1    NA
6  NA   NA   NA   NA
```

What I have tried:
On another SO post, I found this -

`library(stringi)
   res <- as.data.frame(t(stri_list2matrix(myUnstackedList)))
   colnames(res) <- unique(unlist(sapply(myUnstackedList, names)))`

Outcome:

res

```
1  2    4     2    3    3
2  3    3    <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  5   <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>
4  4    4     3   <NA> <NA>
```

Note that the categories A, B, C, D have been changed to 1, 2, 3, 4

Also tried this (another SO post):

```
df <- as.data.frame(plyr::ldply(myUnstackedList, rbind))
```

Outcome:

df

```
outcome   group  score
2         A      2
3         A      2
4         A      1
3         B      2
etc
```

Any tips?

Comment: you can almost get there with `table(stack(test))` but need to tweak this to get the extra levels.. `s = stack(test) ; s$values = factor(s$values, levels=1:6) ;table(s)`

Comment: @user20650, your code results in an interesting true/false table at the moment (where true = 1 and false = 0)

Comment: Work ; using `test` from Alex's answer, it produces your expected outcome, with counts, except NA's are zeros (not TRUE / FALSE?). p.s. you can coerce to dataframe using `as.data.frame.matrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you most of the way to your answer:

```
test <- list(A=c(2,4,2,3,3),
             B=c(3,3),
             C=c(5),
             D=c(4,4,3))
test <- lapply(1:length(test), function(i){
  x <- data.frame(names(test)[i], test[i],
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names(x) <- c("ID", "Value")
  x})
test <- bind_rows(test) %>% table %>% as.data.frame
test <- spread(test, key=ID, value=Freq)
replace(test, test==0, NA)
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. An added bonus is being able to use the outputs from the individual steps to show data in a different way! Thanks @Alex P.

Comment: If you like it, mark it as the answer; but check out Kevin Arseneau's answer too. Its pretty interesting

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the issue was with your previous `dplyr` attempt, however, I offer

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  outcome = c(1:5, 1:2, 1, 1:3),
  group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 2), "C", rep("D", 3)),
  score = c(2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3)
)

df %>%
  group_by(outcome) %>%
  spread(group, score) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-outcome)

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#       A     B     C     D
# * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     2     3     5     4
# 2     4     3    NA     4
# 3     2    NA    NA     3
# 4     3    NA    NA    NA
# 5     3    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: I like how you group_by outcome and spread by group. I'm still trying to wrap my mind around that sweet move

Comment: @Kevin, another great answer. I have been swapping the group_by to see how the data looks with each one. Another great method for visualization. Apologies, I'll edit to include scripts and output for my other attempts.

Comment: @Work, taking a [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) approach is usually the most beneficial

Comment: @Kevin, you are correct. Base dataframes (dataset) can quickly become messy with many variables and calculated columns.